# Some recurring Lightning entries are off by an hour next week

Tags: calendar, timezone, lightning

I just opened my calendar for a few weeks from now (Oct 30 - Nov 5), and some (but not all) of my recurring meetings from my Outlook calendar are off by an hour. My guess is that it has something to do with daylight savings time, since they are correct again after November 5.

For those that are at the correct time, when I look at the details, it says something like:

```
Start Date: Friday, November 3, 2023 9:30 AM
End Date:   Friday, November 3, 2023 10:00 AM
Repeat:     Occurs every Friday effective 8/25/23 until 12/15/23 from 9:30 AM to 10:00 AM.
```

The ones which are off by an hour next week say something like:

```
Start Date: Thursday, November 2, 2023 11:30 AM (Thursday, November 2, 2023 10:30 AM, SystemV/EST5EDT)
End Date:   Thursday, November 2, 2023 12:45 PM (Thursday, November 2, 2023 11:45 AM, SystemV/EST5EDT)
Repeat:     Occurs every Tuesday and Thursday effective 8/22/23 until 12/10/23 from 10:30 AM to 11:45 AM.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure how the timezone got set like that, but I finally figured out how to change it.

1. Double click the event
2. Click "Edit all occurrences"
3. Options > Show timezones
4. Click the timezones (which appear near the start and end times)
5. Change to a "normal" timezone.